# Does the following operator have a name: $\Gamma( a f+b) = a \Gamma(f)$ for all $a>0, b\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $f$?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, terminology

I was reading some literature on concentration inequalities and came across the following operator on the set of functions:
$$\Gamma( a f+b) = a \Gamma(f)$$,
for all $a>0, b\in \mathbb{R}$ and all  $f$.

In the context of concentration inequalities, this operator is thought of as a more general version of a derivative operator.

I have two questions:

Question 1:  Does this operator have a name?

Question 2: Is there treatment of this operator somewhere? That is,  is there a book that studies the proprieties of this operator.

Comment: So the property is homogeneity modulo constants, essentially? Not linearity modulo constants necessarily but homogeneity modulo constants.

Comment: @Ian Correct, homogeneity modulo constant.   Do you know if the linearity modulo constant has a "Name"? We can call this modified "Name" operator.